# Type error is not a function AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to populate a select with an array in AngularJS.
I have an error : TypeError: meanService.getMeanStuff is not a function but I don't find where is the problem...

This is my view :

```
<div id="idName" ng-controller="controllerName">
    Here is my select :
    <select ng-model='modelTypeSelect' ng-options="n for n in meanStuff track by n"></select>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
d3DemoApp.controller('controllerName',function($rootScope,$scope, meanService) {
    $scope.meanStuff = meanService.getMeanStuff();
    $scope.$watch('modelTypeSelect',function(newVal){
        $rootScope.$broadcast(':parameterName',{choice:newVal});
    });
});
```

Service :

```
d3DemoApp.service('meanService', function() {
    this.getMeanStuff = function() {
        return (["data1", "data2", "data3"])
    };
}).service('dataService', function AppCtrl($http, $q) {
    this.getCommitData = function(param) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: param
        }).
        success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve({
                chartData: data,
                error: ''
            });
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
            deferred.resolve({
                error: status
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: in your plunker order of js files included incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong order of scripts first you need to include angular then create the module then include your controllers that use d3DemoApp module:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var d3DemoApp = angular.module('d3DemoApp', []); 
</script>
<script src="ControllerFilterListType.js"></script>
<script src="ServiceFilterListType.js"></script>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/bm8UOrT1mjJyJguAXUUy?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your response, It works on Plunker but on my project, I have an error on $scope.meanStuff = meanService.getMeanStuff();, it says that angular.js:9563 TypeError: meanService.getMeanStuff is not a function. would you know where the problem might be? I'm going crazy ...

Comment: Try recreate the problem in plunker.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the brackets around the return. So:

```
return ["data1", "data2", "data3"]
```

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem.

Comment: You don't need to remove the brackets `(1) === 1`